# Purging from the command line

Tags: 2011

The PurgeTool can be run from the command line with configuration in an XML file. What happens if both the parameters Settings/Keep, Settings/CutOffDate and Scan/Entry@DaysToKeep are all set?

Will the purge tool...

1. Only look at the DaysToKeep parameter on the Scan/Entry element?
2. only purge items which meet the Keep *and* CutOffDate *and* DaysToKeep parameter
3. only purge items which meet the Keep *or* CutOffDate *or* DaysToKeep parameter
4. do something else

I have a case where history is deleted while it did no meet the DaysToKeep parameter so that looks like 1 or 3.

Also see the [Tridion manual](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/idheading-259253576) (login required).

Answer (score 3):

**Per my knowledge** it will only be one option true at one time - Either **Number of Version to Keep** OR **Keep Version Modified After** OR **Day to Keep**.

You are supposed to create you configuration XML by saving from the Purge Tool interface.

Now if you want to play around the XML yourself and put all the options set in to it, it will simply pick up the first option given in the XML and executed.

(Based on my experience so far in SDL Tridion 2009)

Comment: In Tridion 2011 SP1 there is no feature to save the configuration, also the configuration on the level of Entries is available in the config file only. Indeed in the GUI there is a radio button for the Number of Version to Keep OR Keep Version Modified After OR Day to Keep.

Comment: Please check live content site:
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DPurge%2520tool&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1365600954619&currentQuery=Purge%2520tool&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_17A5B947932E4543939ADC18DBEF1C5F&query=&scope=&filename=PurgeToolInterface.xml&docid=concept_17A5B947932E4543939ADC18DBEF1C5F&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=

They claim that you can save the configuration.

Comment: The purge tool that ships with 2011 SP1 has both Save and Load on the file menu, however the save and load functionality looks a bit clunky to me. ISTR that the implementation had to be backwards compatible with an earlier format, which might explain this.